# Compositing backround image not loading right?

Tags: animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

I am trying Composite a green screen clip onto a backround image but when I select the backround image, it only loads a zoomed section of the image? How do I get the full image?

Comment: Try Scale node set to "render size"

Comment: Either adjust background image to render size or adjust render size to bakground image (render settings > dimensions)

Comment: Blender will not autoresize images to fit the render size. Resize the image using a scale or transform node. Also keep in mind that using a render resolution other than 100% will result in cropping.